# Creating a sub site in SharePoint takes a very long time

Tags: sharepoint

I am working in a MOSS 2007 project and have customized many parts of it. There is a problem in the production server where it takes a very long time (more than 15 minutes, sometimes fails due to timeouts) to create a sub site (even with the built-in site templates). While in the development server, it only takes 1 to 2 minutes.

Both servers are having same configuration with 8 cores CPU and 8 GIGs RAM. Both are using separate database servers with the same configuration. The content db size is around 100 GB. More than a hundred subsites are there.

What could be the reason why in the other server it will take so much time? Is there any configuration or something else I need to take care?

### Update:

So today I had the chance to check the environment with my clients. But site creation was so fast though they said they didn't change any configuration in the server.

I also used that chance to examine the database. The disk fragmentation was quite high at 49% so I suggested them to run defrag. And I also asked the database file growth to be increased to 100MB, up from the default 1MB.

So my suspicion is that some processes were running heavily on the server previously, that's why it took that much of time.

### Update 2:

Yesterday my client reported that the site creation was slow again so I went to check it. When I checked the db, I found that instead of the reported **100GB**, the content db size is only around **30GB**. So it's still far below the recommended size.

One thing that got my attention is, the site collection recycle bin was holding almost **5 millions items**. And whenever I tried to browse the site collection recycle bin, it would take a lot of time to open and the whole site collection is inaccessible.

Since the web application setting is set to the default (30 days before cleaning up, and 50% size for the second stage recycle bin), is this normal or is this a potential problem also?

Actually, there was also another web application using the same database server with 100GB content db and it's always fast. But the one with 30GB is slow. Both are having the same setup, only different data.

What should I check next?

---

So today I had the chance to check the environment with my clients. But site creation was so fast though they said they didn't change any configuration in the server.

I also used that chance to examine the database. The disk fragmentation was quite high at 49% so I suggested them to run defrag. And I also asked the database file growth to be increased to 100MB, up from the default 1MB.

So my suspicion is that some processes were running heavily on the server previously, that's why it took that much of time.

Thanks for the inputs everyone, I really appreciate.

---

Yesterday my client reported that the site creation was slow again so I went to check it. When I checked the db, I found that instead of the reported **100GB**, the content db size is only around **30GB**. So it's still far below the recommended size.

One thing that got my attention is, the site collection recycle bin was holding almost **5 millions items**. And whenever I tried to browse the site collection recycle bin, it would take a lot of time to open and the whole site collection is inaccessible.

Since the web application setting is set to the default (30 days before cleaning up, and 50% size for the second stage recycle bin), is this normal or is this a potential problem also?

Actually, there was also another web application using the same database server with 100GB content db and it's always fast. But the one with 30GB is slow. Both are having the same setup, only different data.

Any idea what should I check next? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I know this was from a long time ago, but did you find a solution? I'm seeing exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its normal OOB if you haven't turned the Second Stage Recycle bin off or set a site quota. If a site quota has not been set then the growth of the Second Stage Recycle bin is not limited...

the second stage recycle bin is by default limited to 50% size of the site quota, in other words if you have a site quota of 100gb then you would have a Second Stage recycle bin of 50gb. If a site quota has not been set, there are not any growth limitations...

Answer (score 0):

Backup the production database to dev and attach it to your dev SharePoint server.
Try and create a site. If it does not take forever to create a site, you can assume there is a problem with the Prod database.

Despite that, at 100gig, you are running up to the limit for a content database and should be planning to put content into more than one. you will know why when you try and backup the database. Searching should also be starting to take a good long time now.

So long term you are going to have to plan on splitting your websites out into different content databases.

**--Responses--**

Yeah, database size is all just about SQL server handling it. 100GB is just the "any more than this and it starts to be a pain" rule of thumb. Full Search crawls will also start a while.

Given that you do not have access to the production database and that creating a sub-site is primarily a database operation, there is nothing you can really do to figure out what the issue is.

You could try creating a subsite while doing a trace of the Dev database and look at the tables those commands reference to see if there is a smoking gun, but without production access you are really hampered.

Does the production system server pages and documents at a reasonable speed? 
See if you can start getting some stats from the database during the creation, find out what work is being done. SQL has some great tools for that now.

Comment: Hi Nat,

Thanks for the response. Unfortunately the clients won't give the production database backup since it contains sensitive data. I know it's difficult to analyze without checking the real environment, but I don't have that option. Just checking what can be the possible reasons.

Comment: About using different content dbs, it's also difficult since all the subsites are inter-related to each other. Moving them to different content dbs will break the relations, links, and the codes to create and maintain them. Since all subsites are user-created, it's also difficult to control.

Comment: One subsite its-self can have more than 100GB content, making it more difficult to manage.

I know 100GB is the recommended size, but I believe it's not the limit. Joel Oleson from SharePoint team also mentioned that there's no limit in content db size. The limit would be in the SQL Server capacity.

Comment: Yeah, you can kiss automatic navigation goodbye when you break out in a severe case of site collections.

Answer (score 0):

I second everything [Nat has said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564670/creating-a-sub-site-in-sharepoint-takes-a-very-long-time/569239#569239) and emphasize splitting the content database. There are [instructions on how to this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc825328.aspx) provided you have multiple site collections and not a single massive one.

Also check your SharePoint databases are in good shape. Have you tried DBCC CHECKDB? Do you have SQL Server maintenance plans configured to reindex and reduce fragmentation? Read [these resources on TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263420.aspx) (particularly the database maintenance article) for details.

Finally, see if there is anything more you can do to isolate the SQL Server as the problem. Are there any other applications with databases on the same SQL Server and are they having problems? Are you running performance monitoring on the SQL Server or SharePoint servers that show any bottlenecks?

Comment: Hi Alex,

Thanks for the recommendation. Since I don't have direct access to the production database, I'll pass the info to the production team. Thanks.